# Convert ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone class into String "ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so I have a really fascinating meta programming issue here.

I'm trying to check what the class of an object is in ruby so I have a method that looks like this:

```rb
attri = "created_at"

def convert_value_dataype(object)
  klass = object.send(attri.to_sym).class.to_s
  case klass
  when "String"
    return get_attri(object)
  when "NilClass"
    return nil
  when "Fixnum"
    return get_attri(object).to_i
  when "ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone" || "DateTime"
    return DateTime.parse(get_attri(object))
  when "TrueClass"
    return true
  when "FalseClass"
    return false
  when "Float"
    return get_attri(object).to_f
  else
    raise "Unkown dataype: #{klass}"
  end
end
```

Now the interesting thing is that this works when the attribute I'm looking at is a Fixnum or something simple, eg. attri = "id" but I get this error when I run the code: TypeError: no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into String.

However when I run this in the console I can type user.send("created_at".to_sym).class.to_s and I get the correct output. Is there something special that gets imported when I'm using console (pry) that isn't being imported when I'm running the app?

I can also put 'binding.pry' right above the line "klass = ..." and call that exact line and it works in the pry console, but as soon as I exit the pry console it errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out my issue. The error is occuring in the line `return DateTime.parse(get_attri(object))` because I'm trying to parse an ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone object into a DateTime.